# reset the css of a input[radio]

Tags: css

I searched but did not find any answers and I need to understand.  I am noob to css etc.. But I'm learning quickly.
I recently copied some code (shame on me I don't recall the authors name) that creates tabs using pure css.  The tabs code uses radio input's.  So to hide the radio element the author did the following:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}
```

but later in my code I need a standard radio button (vanilla html) and I don't know how to reset the style for one element.  I can use a fancy css radio button and that does appear to work.  But still the bigger question is how does one reset the values for any one element?  I can say "all: initial;"  does not do the trick.

Comment: Indicate what research you've done on the matter, what code you've tried toward reaching your objective, and in what ways your attempts have failed.

Comment: I've searched google with several different search criteria all with "css radio button".  I believe I have successfully determined that the prior css code setting the radio button/label is the root cause of my issue.  That said, I still do not know how to reset the properties to a normal state for any tag (element?).  I did attempt  :not(input[radio]) which did not work at any level in the DOM.  Opening the developer tools reveals that the prior css code is still there.  Interesting that I got the test code provided to work - but still had placement issues with the button not next to the text.

Comment: Think about the scope of the changes you are making. If you are creating tabs from radio buttons is there an enclosing element you can specify in the css rule that will cause that change to only apply to your tabs? If there is not can you add a class to the radio buttons you want to turn into tabs?

Comment: I did try in my surrounding selector ":not(.grid-content)" in the following places:
where ".tab-wrap label" and in"input[type="radio"]" believing that the outside selector would protect the elements inside it from changes outside of it.  That did not work.

Comment: I think I'm using :not() incorrectly!  Is there a way to limit the styling to not include a div (and it's siblings)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood you but if you want to make different radio buttons with custom and default styles I advice you to give different classes to these radio buttons wrapers

Here the example

```
<form action="#" class=form-1>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="test1" name="radio-group" checked>
    <label for="test1">Apple</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="test2" name="radio-group">
    <label for="test2">Peach</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="test3" name="radio-group">
    <label for="test3">Orange</label>
  </p>
</form>

<form action="#" class=form-2>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="test1" name="radio-group" checked>
    <label for="test1">Apple</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="test2" name="radio-group">
    <label for="test2">Peach</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="test3" name="radio-group">
    <label for="test3">Orange</label>
  </p>
</form>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MQLbdM

I forked it from another example to demonstrate you what i mean

There are two forms. I customized only those radio buttons which are in FORM-1 (see css)

but radio buttons in FORM-2 are still default

Comment: I will study the code you provided.  I believe the issue has to due with the structure of the css code.  If I just place the radio button on the form it looks like a tab (created by the earlier css code elements).  In your case the code is more specific and is clearly identified.  I'm just learning and I am not sure how to make the tab's code only work with the tabs and not the rest of the css code.  The "tabs" author is using the label and radio buttons in his/her code allow the switching of content without the use of javascript.

Comment: I added your code directly (had to add the parent selectors) but at least it shows.  That said, the buttons do not line up with the text - they are high. They do work.  Also, I need them inline (next to each other and NOT on top of each other.  So again I believe the prior css for the labels and radio buttons is the root cause and I need to some how fix that property.

Comment: First thanks to everyone for trying to help.  In the I used the code that replaces the radio button style.  This works and is just fine for my project.  But in the end I did not learn how to reset the radio buttons.  In fact what I believe the above code does is re-define the radio button styles and allows the new radio button to work.  That is what I wanted to do with some sort reset command.  BTW "all:initial" or "all.unset" did not work.

Comment: @Johnf I think you need -webkit-appearance

Comment: I did try "-webkit-appearance"  and it had no effect.  Just removing the css code for the tabs (then the tabs look like radio buttons) allows me to use the standard radio buttons lower in my HTML code.  I believe there should be a way to reset - if I were using float-left  I can clear:both but there is nothing to just reset a radio button styling default.  There must be some reason this is true - but being so new to web programming I'm just not aware of the reason.

Comment: I actually have it fixed - not that I completely understand the fix.  There are so many gotcha's either in the html, js, or the css that I wonder why I chose this environment.  Anyway, I'll thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `display: none` to hide  an element. This method is just bad. Then you can simply don't touch any other value, and recall it like: `display: block`.

You can simply do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleButton() {
    var e = document.getElementById("my_button");

    if (e.style.display === "none") {
        e.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        e.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

<input type="radio" id="my_button" />
<input type="submit" onclick="toggleButton()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the "display:block and display: none" trick.  I'll use in the future for sure.
That said, I did discover a way to deal with my problem.  Actually, I don't know why I didn't think of it earlier (but then I wouldn't have learned about the above trick).  I went to the W3 site and found the radio buttons and used chromes development tool to discover the css use in the standard way.  I just added all the standard stuff back in and it worked.  I'm not sure that is the most effective of getting it done but it did work. At least I can see the circle again!

Comment: Turns out I jumped the gun on my solution - the radio button now appear and I can click on them but they act like checkboxes.  I'll guess and say there is still some css that over writes the action and needs to be reset.

Answer (score 0):

below is the css where below .tab-content I need to be not influenced by the tab code (I want to be able to use a label tag without how the label looking like a tab, and I want the radio button to be normal with buttons and text)

```
*, *:after, *:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    min-width:1470px;        /* Suppose you want minimum width of 1000px */
    width: auto !important;  /* Firefox will set width as auto */
    background: #eee;

}
div.pes_header{  
    display: inline-block;     
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient( limegreen,transparent ),
                linear-gradient(90deg,skyblue, transparent),
                linear-gradient(-90deg, coral, transparent);
    background-size: cover;
    background-size: contain;
    /* -webkit-background-size: cover; */
    background-blend-mode: no-repeat;   
}

.page-wrap {
    width: 98%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

textarea {
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    /* top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px; */
    display:none;
}

.tab-wrap  {
      width: 100%;
      float: none;
      list-style: none;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: left;
}

.tab-wrap li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.tab-wrap  label  {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em .5em .5em;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0px;
}


.label-1 {
    z-index: 100;
}

.label-2 {
    z-index: 90;
}


.label-3 {
    z-index: 80;
}
.label-4 {
    z-index: 80;
}
.label-5 {
    z-index: 80;
}
.label-6 {
    z-index: 80;
}
.label-7 {
    z-index: 80;
}
.label-8 {
    z-index: 80;
}
.label-9 {
    z-index: 80;
}

.tab-wrap label:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    border: .1em solid #aaa;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    /* background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(229,229,229,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%);

    /* -webkit-transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg); */
        transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);

    /* -webkit-transform-origin: left;
        -ms-transform-origin: left; */
            transform-origin: left;
}

.tab-wrap .tab-content {
    z-index: 200;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0, 10px ,20px, 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: .1em solid #aaa;
    border-top: 0;

}

.tab-wrap [id^="tab"]:checked + label {
    z-index: 200;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
}

.tab-wrap [id^="tab"]:checked + label:before {
    /* background: #baebb0; */
    background: linear-gradient( limegreen,transparent ),
                linear-gradient(90deg,skyblue, transparent),
                linear-gradient(-90deg, coral, transparent);
    background-size: cover;
    background-size: contain;
    /* -webkit-background-size: cover; */
    background-blend-mode: no-repeat;  
}

.tab-wrap [id^="tab"]:checked ~ .tab-content{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I want to thank all of you folks for trying to help me.  I hope in the future I will be able to assist others when I learn how to code this correctly.