# Resetting only a specific radio button group to CSS defaults?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on modifying a *large* project that uses HTML and CSS, among other things.

I need to re-style just one radio button group - so it has buttons *and* labels, not just labels.  I specifically don't want to re-style the whole project's buttons - it's too big to wade through all that and risk messing up other parts of it.

Right now, the buttons look like:
[image]

But I want them to look more like (with Preserved and Unpreserved):
[image]

I've tried more things than I can count, but most recently...

I tried the following CSS (minified):

```
.un_preserve_radio{all:initial;visibility:visible;appearance:radio;opacity:1;position:fixed;width:100%;-webkit-appearance:radio;-moz-appearance:radio;-O-appearance:radio}
```

With the following HTML:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="un_preserved" onclick="preserved_button_click()" class="un_preserve_radio" />
    Preserved
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="un_preserved" onclick="unpreserved_button_click()" class="un_preserve_radio" />
    Unpreserved
</label>
```

Update: I just tried this HTML, which gave me black text (or blue text if I eliminate the "all: initial"):

```
<div style="color:blue; all: initial; visibility: visible;">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="un_preserved" onclick="preserved_button_click()" class="un_preserve_radio" />
        Preserved
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="un_preserved" onclick="unpreserved_button_click()" class="un_preserve_radio" />
        Unpreserved
    </label>
    <br />
</div>
```

This is almost a duplicate of [reset the css of a input[radio]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039747/reset-the-css-of-a-inputradio) - but I really do want to reset just one radio button group to CSS defaults.

Comment: One immediate observation is the CSS that you have references `un_preserve_radio` without a period at the beginning. I'm not sure if that was a copy and paste issue or how your code actually is.

Comment: @imvain2 You're right, it was a cut-and-paste error.  Thanks for pointing out the missing ".".

Comment: It renders without the buttons in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Comment: I created a toy web page with the CSS from one of the labels' "Computed" tab in Chrome's Inspect, but did not get a replication.

Comment: Could this be a clue?  When I mouseover the full app's "<input type..." in Chrome's Inspect, I see: "input.un_preserve_radio  0 x 0".  Does that mean the radio buttons have 0x0 dimensions?

Comment: This appears to have helped, but is not a complete solution: style="width: 1em; height: 1em; overflow: visible; opacity: 1!important"
I can now see a square on the left edge of the label where the button should be, in Inspect.  I'm not all the way there yet though, because I still don't have a visible button.]

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted the current CSS that is changing the radio/labels, I have a quick sample here.

First, I gave the wrapping div a class called "radio-override".

Then in CSS, I set the radio children of that class to have the visibility of visible. Then I also gave the label children a color of black and display of block to force each label/radio to a new line.

```css
.radio-override input[type='radio']{
  visibility: visible;
}

.radio-override label{
  color: black;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-override">
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="un_preserved" onclick="preserved_button_click()" class="un_preserve_radio" />
        Preserved
    </label>
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="un_preserved" onclick="unpreserved_button_click()" class="un_preserve_radio" />
        Unpreserved
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what part of our CSS is changing/breaking the radio buttons.  The only thing I see that stands out at all is a checkbox display: none.  I gave your .radio-override a try, changing the black to lightblue so I could see the result better. Sadly, the buttons are still missing; it's labels only.

Answer (score 0):

I needed (for example):

```
<input type="radio" name="un_preserved" onclick="preserved_button_click()" style="width: 1em; height: 1em; overflow: visible; opacity: 1!important" />
```

That !important was needed to override 4 global settings.

I also needed to move a `<br />`, but the `!important` was the.... most important part.